# "Oops! Something went wrong" when trying to get spotipy token

Tags: python, spotify, spotipy

I'm trying to access my library using spotipy and have the following code:

```
import spotipy
import spotipy.util as util


clientid = 'myid'
clientsecret = 'mysecret'
username = 'myname'
scopes = 'user-library-modify playlist-modify-private'
redirect = 'localhost:8888/callback'


def getToken(SPOTIPY_CLIENT_ID, SPOTIPY_CLIENT_SECRET, username, scope, redirect):

    token = util.prompt_for_user_token(username,
                                    scope,
                                    client_id=SPOTIPY_CLIENT_ID,
                                    client_secret=SPOTIPY_CLIENT_SECRET,
                                    redirect_uri=redirect)

    if token:
        print('Token successfully obtained!')
        return token
    else:
        print('Failed to get token!')
        return 0



getToken(clientid, clientsecret, username, scopes, redirect)
```

This does one of two things: It will open up another browser window and give an option to click "Okay" or "Cancel", neither of which does anything when I click them; or it will give me the following error:

[image]

The `Enter the URL you were redirected to:` prompt that I get seems to throw a `Bad Request` error whenever I try to put in either my redirect url as defined above or URL I'm directed to, with the Client ID and Client Secret verbatim.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce your error. what URL does it give when displaying the authorization options?

Comment: @mangoHero1 it opens `https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?client_id=[myclientid]&response_type=code&redirect_uri=localhost%3A8888%2Fcallback&scope=playlist-modify-private+user-library-modify in your browser`. I should add I'm on Ubuntu; there seemed to be a cache issue here (https://github.com/plamere/spotipy/issues/163) but I can't interpret how to fix it

Comment: have you whitelisted the callback URI in your application page? what exactly does it say?

Comment: yeah, although not the longer URL in my last comment. is that supposed to be whitelisted as well?

Comment: No :-) though I'm not on Ubuntu. Try setting it to `http://localhost:8888/callback/` with the http part and the slash at the end. Dunno if that makes any difference. Although you might try your luck using the other authorization flow.

Comment: Yeah, I've already whitelisted that and I'm still getting this problem :(